# Separability of the nearest power of two function

Tags: arithmetic

I have a function $f$ given by

$f(x)=nearest\ upper\ power\ of\ two\ of\ x$

For example, $f(5)=8$ and $f(2)=2$.

Are $f(x \wedge y)$ and $f(x+y\mod{N})$ separable over some operator. For example, could we do:

$f(x\wedge y)=g(x)g(y)$

or

$f(x+y\mod{N})=g(x)\ op\ g(y)$

where $op$ is some arbitrary operator.

In other words, what can be done algebraically with the nearest power of two function?

In Warren's Hacker's delight, we have that the nearest power of two function is given by:

$
f(x)=1<<(32-nlz(x-1)-1)
$

on a 32 bit register and with $nlz$ being the number of leading zeros. Maybe this is of use?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "nearest upper power of two of $x$", you mean $\min\,\{2^n\mid x\in\mathbb{N}, 2^n\ge x\}$ (or, equivalently, $2^{\lceil \log n\rceil}$)?

Comment: There's a good definition here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-off-to-nearest-power-of-2

Comment: No, there is no definition there. That post also just gives an example. I have never in my life before today heard the phrase "least upper power of two". I've suggested the definition that seems to fit your examples: how hard is it to say "yes" or "no"?

Comment: What do you mean by $\land$?  Do you mean logical AND (as in mathematical notation) or XOR (as in C code)?

Comment: Isn't this a pure mathematics question?

Comment: I meant $\wedge$ = AND

Answer (score 2):

No, $f(x+y)$ is not separable.

Consider: $f(3+5)=8$.  Also $f(3)=4$ and $f(5)=8$.

At the same time, $f(4+5)=16$.  Also $f(4)=4$ and $f(5)=8$.

It follows that $f(x+y)$ is not determined by $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ (consider $y=5$, $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$), so there is no function $h$ such that $f(x+y)=h(f(x),f(y))$.